# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when trying to run TornadoFX Application

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Not sure what is causing it to not find the "init" function on my View, so I thought I'd post here and see if anyone else had this issue.

Everything compiles ok! And then when I run my program I get this error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.my.tfx.app.InputView
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
  at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:372)
  at tornadofx.FXKt.find$default(FX.kt:358)
  at tornadofx.App.start(App.kt:80)
  at com.my.tfx.app.UserInputUI.start(UserInputUI.kt:15)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.my.tfx.app.InputView.<init>()
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
  ... 13 more
```

Not quite sure what is causing this.. I have a setup like this:

```
class UserInputUI : App(InputView(SVGEnum.first, StringEnum.first, UserInput.validationFunctions)::class, UIStyles::class) {
  init {
    reloadStylesheetsOnFocus()
  }

  override fun start(stage: Stage) {
    super.start(stage)
    stage.minWidth = 1024.0
    stage.minHeight = 768.0
    stage.maxWidth = 2560.0
    stage.maxHeight = 1440.0
  }
}

class InputView(val s: SVGEnum, val q: StringEnum, val valFunArray : ArrayList<(String)-> Boolean>) : View() {

  override val root = stackpane {
    //contents ommitted cause they're super long and I dont think its relevant,
    //but I can add it in if requested
  }

}
```

Any ideas? Or is this a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views must have a no args constructor, so that they can be instantiated by the framework. In your app subclass (`UserInputUI`) you actually instantiate `InputView` youtrself and then call `::class` to get the KClass of it. You're only supposed to pass it the KClass directly, so you need to modify your code so that `UserInputUI` is defined like this:

```
class UserInputUI : App(InputView::class, UIStyles::class)
```

(I have omitted the init block and the start override. By the way, make sure you don't call `reloadStylesheetsOnFocus` in production. To make sure that never makes it into production, remove it and set the option in the TornadoFX IDEA Run Configuration istead).

Next, you must make sure that `InputView` has a noargs constructor. You need to use another technique to pass parameters into it. Since you hard coded them in your App class you might just hard code them directly in `InputView` as well, or you can introduce a `ViewModel` that you configure in `App.start` based on command line parameters or a configuration file if you like.

A rewrite that simply hardcodes the values in `InputView` instead of `UserInputIU` would look something like this:

```
class InputView() : View() {
    val s: SVGEnum = SVGEnum.first
    val q: StringEnum = StringEnum.first
    val valFunArray: ArrayList<(String) -> Boolean> = UserInput.validationFunctions

    override val root = stackpane {
    }
}
```

I hope that clarifies the issue :)

Comment: Ah, thank you! Did not realise I couldn't use parameters in my Views.

Comment: You can use parameters or scoped objects like ViewModel to send information between views, check out the guide for more information:)